# How I can create mocked views for my database that app has no migration scripts for it?

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing

I have the following architecture of my application:

[image: 2 Applications named App1 and App2 app1 connects with 2 databases whilst appi2 contains with one. App1 has migration scripts for the one of the databases whilst app2 has fot the another.]

As you can see App1 is able to migrate Db1 whilst App2 is able to migrate Db2. App1 accesses only the views `my_view1` and `my_view2` from Db2.

Upon unit testing at App1 how I can create "fake" views with mock data that represent the actual views `my_view1` and `my_view2`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make test views you'll need to generate an initial SQL script, that will generate a table similar to the view and the view will be just a select * from the table we generated:

```
psql -U your_user your_database -c "CREATE TABLE my_view1_mock as select * FROM my_view_1";
pg_dump -U your_user your_database -t my_view1_mock --schema-only > mock_views.sql
echo "CREATE OR REPLACE view my_view_1 as SELECT * FROM my_view1_mock" >> mock_views.sql

psql -U your_user your_database -c "CREATE TABLE my_view2_mock as select * FROM my_view_2";
pg_dump -U your_user your_database -t my_view2_mock --schema-only >> mock_views.sql
echo "CREATE OR REPLACE view my_view_2 as SELECT * FROM my_view2_mock" >> mock_views.sql
```

In another words we make a script `mock_views.sql` that will create the fake views. The `mock_views.sql` will be executed from unit-testing (such as `phpunit`) tool before running the actual test at tool's execution runtime. Therefore, empty test databases will need to be initialized as well for both Db1 and Db2.

The test data need to be populated in tables `my_view2_mock` and `my_view1_mock` in order to be shown in the actual views. Keep in mind this approach hides any logic/data population from the actual tables that populate the views.

---

In case of phpunit used the reccomended place to execute the sql script is at `setUp` method.